# Google Apps Script - Gmail, delete forever e-mails in trash with specific label

Tags: javascript, gmail, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a script that automatically deletes e-mails from a certain sender immediately and permanently, as Gmail only allows for a filter which sends an e-mail to trash for 30 days. Please do not suggest that the default filter is enough, as for my situation, it is vital that I do not know that I was sent an e-mail from this sender.

My current script looks like this:

```
function deleteForever(labelName) {
    var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash label:" + labelName);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].moveToTrash(); // Where I would need a delete forever trigger
    }
};
```

However, I have been unable to figure out a way to use a GmailThread and to delete it permanently as there does not exist a function for this purpose. I was looking to see if there was a way I could finish the task using JavaScript, but have been unable figure out a method.

Does anyone have an idea how I can set these e-mails to delete themselves permanently when received?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible in `GmailApp`, by design, to permanently delete an email.

But you can use the advanced service `Gmail`, as written in the other answers here

Comment: As I feared. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: Once it was the right answer but since we have the advanced services it is possible to remove an email.

Comment: Yep Edo's right, it's entirely possible to permanently and immediately delete emails using the Gmail Advanced Service now. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced for how to enable an advanced service. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail for more details about the Gmail Advanced Service. And check out Daniel Bultas' script for the piece of code that will remove messages (Gmail.Users.Messages.remove).

Answer (score 21):

@karan's answer already points to the solution which worked for me, but being inexperienced / not-a-professional-developer, it took me a little work to translate it into a working solution to the original question. Here's a concise description of the steps I used to perform this task:

1. Create the following function in my script:

   ```
   function deleteForever(userId, labelName) {
     var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash label:" + labelName);
     for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
       Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, threads[i].getId());
     }
   }
   ```
2. To enable advanced services for this script, locate `Resources` on the menu, and select `Advanced Google services...`
3. Enable `Gmail API` on the list.
4. Before selecting `OK`, click on the `Google Developers Console` link. Search for `gmail`, and enable the service there as well.
5. Done, select `OK`; the function should now work. (Comment: as mentioned in [the link @karan provided](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete), one can use `"me"` for userID, or alternatively provide one's Gmail address: `"<address>@gmail.com"`.)

(Steps to enable advanced services for my script are based on Google's guide [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).)

Comment: **[Here is a link](https://www.google.com/script/start/)** to Google App Scripts, where you'll need to be in order to perform the steps above.  Just click that link, then click the `Start Scripting` button, and you'll be able to perform steps easily.

Comment: @Bryce Larson I see that you suggested to change `Messages` into `Threads`. Have you tested the script that way? If so, and you can comment on the advantage of doing that, I'll be happy to accept. (FWIW it's been working for me the way it's currently written for the past year.)

Comment: I would also recommend changing to **threads**  `Gmail.Users.Threads.remove`.  `GmailApp.search` returns an array of threads per [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)).  In this case, I believe threads are being removed rather than messages.  In my case, I was getting the following error (`API call to gmail.users.messages.delete failed with error: Not Found`) before realizing that I was passing a thread ID to the `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove` function.

Comment: 2022 UPDATE: with the new editor, just click on Services on the left side and select GMail API. After that the above code worked just fine

Comment: @Shlomo: That is incorrect. `Gmail`  class is only accessible after the Service has been added to the Google Apps script project (Steps 2-5 in OP's post). Permanent deletion as per OP's post still works as of this writing.

Comment: @AshutoshJindal You're right, thanks for the info. I deleted my previous comment so as not to mislead

Answer (score 9):

This script works for Google Apps Script. You have to just connect and auth services together.

```
function myFunction() {

  var labelName = "deleteForever"

  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash label:" + labelName);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { 
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', threads[i].getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: how to do this in bulk?

Comment: It won't work anymore, the `Gmail` class no longer exists (and its replacement - `GmailApp` has no such method)

Comment: @Shlomo: That is incorrect. `Gmail`  class is only accessible after the Service has been added to the Google Apps script project (Steps 2-5 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799896/325742). Permanent deletion as per OP's post still works as of this writing.

Answer (score 5):

If it helps someone, it can be done using the advanced services.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete

The method in advanced services is

`Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, id)`

Comment: It's nice to know about this, but this is more a comment than an answer as long as it doesn't explain how to use that method in the original question; what lines should be added / changed? E.g., should the line in the loop be replaced with `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, threads[i].getId());`?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a supporting comment to @JonathanY's  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799896/325742 :

### **** Pre-requisite****

Note that being able to permanently delete messages or threads relies on `Gmail` class which is only accessible once that Service has been added to the project like so:

###### Step 1: Click on `+` in Services

[image: Click On Services]

(Note that there are no Services currently listed here)

###### Step 2:

Scroll down to the Gmail Service, select it and then click Add

[image: Add Gmail Service]

###### Step 3:

Finally, confirm that the service now appears in the list of Services:

[image]

---

### Sample Code

To re-iterate, the following sample code needs to be in a project which has the `Gmail` service added to it as above.

To test this code, choose any message in Bin and label it with `deleteForever` (create this label if needed).

Leave `dryRun` as true and execute the function. The output will show which threads and/or messages will get deleted.

In actual usage, if you are planning to delete entire threads via `Gmail.Users.Threads.remove` then you wouldn't use `checkMessagesForContentBeforeDeleting` since the latter checks individual message bodies for content before deleting them (i.e. will only delete individual messages matching 'body content has the specified regex' criteria) and not whole threads.

```
var dryRun = true;

String.prototype.indexOfRegex = function (regex) {
  var match = this.match(regex);
  return match ? this.indexOf(match[0]) : -1;
}

function testDeleteForever() {
  var labelName = "deleteForever"
  var badContentFilterForMessages = ".*08:29.*"
  var gmailSearchString = `in:trash label:${labelName}`

  var threads = GmailApp.search(gmailSearchString);
  const n = threads.length;
  if (n <= 0) {
    Logger.log("No threads matching search string \"%s\"", gmailSearchString);
    return
  } else {
    Logger.log("Found %s threads matching action **%s**", n, gmailSearchString);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    Logger.log(`\t Processing Thread#${i} [ID: ${thread.getId()}]: [First message subject: ${thread.getFirstMessageSubject()}]`)

    if (!dryRun) {
      Logger.log(`\t \t Will delete forever the THREAD: ${thread.getFirstMessageSubject()}`)
      Gmail.Users.Threads.remove('me', thread.getId())
    } else {
      Logger.log(`\t \t **DRY RUN** would have deleted forever the THREAD: ${thread.getFirstMessageSubject()}`)
    }

    checkMessagesForContentBeforeDeleting(thread, badContentFilterForMessages);
  }
}

function checkMessagesForContentBeforeDeleting(thread, badContentFilterForMessages){
    Logger.log(`\t \t Checking messages in ${thread.getId()} for content matching "${badContentFilterForMessages}" before deleting forever`)
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    Logger.log(`\t \t Number of messages in ${thread.getId()}: ${messages.length} `)

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      Logger.log(`\t \t \t Checking Message#${j}: [Subject: ${message.getSubject()}]`)

      var body = message.getRawContent();
      var containsSearchString = body.indexOfRegex(badContentFilterForMessages) > -1;

      if (containsSearchString) {
        Logger.log(`\t \t \t \t Message#${j} is a match! Will be deleted!`)
        if (!dryRun) {
          Logger.log(`\t \t \t \t Will delete forever the MESSAGE: ${message.getSubject()}`)
          Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', message.getId());
        } else {
          Logger.log(`\t \t \t \t **DRY RUN** would have deleted forever.`)
          Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', message.getId());
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log(`\t \t \t \t NOT deleting the MESSAGE (content does not match)`)
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function delete_all_mail(){
var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1AG1fZ9BuS8***********');
var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//0~500
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0 , 500);
  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
   threads[i].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not permanently deleted like the OP requested

Answer (score 0):

Better performance in the case of multiple messages, by using [`batchDelete`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/batchDelete) instead of multiple calls to the remove method:

```
function deleteForever (labelName, emailAccount = 'me') {
    const threads = GmailApp.search('in:trash label:' + labelName);
    const messages = threads.map(thread => thread.getMessages()).flat();
    const messagesIds = messages.map(message => message.getId());
    if (!threads.length) {
        return console.log('not emails to delete');
    }
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete({ ids: messagesIds }, emailAccount);
    console.log(`${messages.length} messages in ${threads.length} threads deleted forever`);
}
// example call to function:
// deleteForever('labelName')
```

**Note:** before using the script, you need to enable the `Gmail` advanced service (from [Google Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?authuser=0&hl=he#enable_advanced_services)):

###### Step 1: Click on `+` in Services

Click "+" On Services section:
[image]

(Note that there are no Services currently listed here)

###### Step 2:

Scroll down to the Gmail Service, select it and then click Add

[image]

###### Step 3:

Finally, confirm that the service now appears in the list of Services:

[image]