# Gmail /Google apps deleting trash email forever Hourly/Daily using script/api automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Is there a script/API way to delete trash email forever from Gmail/GoogleApps?

Any related help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing, however it seems to be by design impossible, according to this post:

[Google Apps Script - Gmail, delete forever e-mails in trash with specific label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995031/google-apps-script-gmail-delete-forever-e-mails-in-trash-with-specific-label)

I also found this post:

https://www.dragonsreach.it/2011/07/03/automatic-gmails-trash-spam-folders-cleanup/

but I am not sure if it is a good idea to follow it.