# Script to permenantly delete my emails with Google Script

Tags: javascript, java, gmail, gmail-api

How does this Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, id) work? What is the ID of the email and is it the right function to permanently delete an email?

In my case I want to delete all my sent emails instantly and definitely. Here's some code I took from someone, only with a different label:

```
function myFunction() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:sent label:Inbox");
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, threads[i]);
    }

}
```

Is this in anyway correct and could anyone help me please?

Edit: I modified my code but it's still not working ,I still can't figure out how to use the function remove,  here's it:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var thread = Gmail.Users.Threads.list(me);
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(me, thread);
        thread = Gmail.Users.Threads.list(me).nextPageToken;
     
  }

}
```

Once the code is working , I'll put a trigger to run the function every minute. So that my Sent folder is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my side I was using this

```
 thread.moveToTrash();
```

(Agree that trash is maybe not what you expect..)

Doc google (en): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#movetotrash

Post (fr) : http://curiositedevie.blogspot.be/2015/08/gmail-gestion-de-vos-emails-aux-petits.html?m=1

Full sample script(en): https://github.com/boly38/script.google.com/blob/master/organizeEmail.gs

---

EDIT: Here is a solution to remove permanently a thread

Use `Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(mymail, thread.id);` like in the sample under.

How To use the sample :

- Update your gmail address (at the first execution you will be asked for the related authorizations).
- I strongly recommand to play first time using `permanentlyRemoveMyLabel = false`. In this case, this sample will display (and keep) the message with `label:mytest`
- Once done, set `permanentlyRemoveMyLabel` to `true`. In this case, this sample will display and **permanently remove** the message with `label:mytest`.

Sample for https://script.google.com/ :

```
function removeMyTest() {
  var mymail = "myemailhere@gmail.com";
  var mylabel = "mytest";
  var permanentlyRemoveMyLabel = false;
  var pageToken;
  do {
    var threadList = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {
      q: 'label:' + mylabel,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (threadList.threads && threadList.threads.length > 0) {
      threadList.threads.forEach(function(thread) {
        Logger.log('id: %s snippet: %s', thread.id, thread.snippet);
        if (permanentlyRemoveMyLabel) {
          Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(mymail, thread.id);
          Logger.log('id: %s snippet: %s REMOVED', thread.id, thread.snippet);
        }
      });
    }
    pageToken = threadList.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, I've read that it is possible to definitely delete an email without it going to trash folder, with the Advanced Google Services , using the Gmail Api. Here's the topic https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete . I just didn't figure out how to use it , I must say that my programming skills are aweful, but I'm still learning.

Comment: I think this v1 "delete(...)" ReST API is not wrapped by any 'apps-script' method because there is no delete method into [apps-script/reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/), and even no way to empty the trash .. :(

Comment: exactly , but there must be a way , because the script given in this link : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete works perfectly if the correct id is given. all i need to know is how to get the id of an email so I can run correctly my function.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly !! It's EXACTLY what I was looking for , thank you !

Comment: You need to enable the advanced google services (under resources and under console api) for Gmail

Comment: @boly38: Your script is cancelled automatically after deleing emails from the crashed. lets say i have 20000 emails then scripts is cancelled automatically after deleting 5000 emails

Comment: @SeleniumUser thanks for your feedback ! 
you could maybe create an issue on related repository https://github.com/boly38/script.google.com/issues : I didn't touch this since a while 
 and you could maybe contribute: adding to the issue some limitation and maybe suggest workaround ..

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging in the docs. With the result you want, I think what you are looking for is [User.messages.delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete). As mentioned in the docs:

> Immediately and **permanently deletes** the specified message. This operation cannot be undone.

As per the `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove()`, I'm not sure with this, but I think that its an old implementation, because I looked around the community and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453518/4625829) providing it as the snippet for permanently deleting an email/message. I'd stick to what the current docs says though.

Comment: I just cannot fint this command User.messages.delete in https://script.google.com , I'm working on the web version. The only available command is remove().

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all of the conversations from the sent folder. NB If someone sent you a message and you responded that would be part of the same conversation, and I think that the incoming message would be deleted as well. This may not be what you want.

```
function DeleteByLabel() {

  var label="sent"
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" +label);
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log("Found " + threads.length + " threads with label " + label);

  for (var i = threads.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
     var thisid=threads[i].getId();
     Logger.log("Removing thread " +i + ' of ' + threads.length + " from " + label + " with ID = " + thisid);

    try {
        Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(me, thisid);
    }
    catch(err) {
     Logger.log("Error " + err.message + " when removing thread with ID " +thisid);
    };
}

}
```

Tried it on my "Drafts" folder and it got rid of those Ok.

NB You will have to enable the appropriate Gmail API when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

add it to google script.

```
function Intialize() {
  return;
}

function Install() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("purgeGmail")
           .timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
}

function Uninstall() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
  for (var i=0; i<triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
function purgeGmail() {
  var search = "category:forums";
  var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 500);
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This used to work until mid-Feb 2017.

I used this to empty my trash

```
  `var threads = GmailApp.getTrashThreads(0, 100);
  for (var i = threads.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
        Logger.log("Removing thread " +i + ' of ' + threads.length + " from Trash");
    try {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(me, threads[i].getId());
    } catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error " + err.message);
    };
  }
  Logger.log("Finished removing " + threads.length + " threads from Trash.");`
```

It has now stopped working and is giving these errors:

```
`17-02-25 02:10:53:510 PST] Removing thread 1 of 2 from Trash
[17-02-25 02:10:53:620 PST] Error Not Found
[17-02-25 02:10:53:621 PST] Removing thread 0 of 2 from Trash
[17-02-25 02:10:53:763 PST] Error Not Found
[17-02-25 02:10:53:764 PST] Finished removing 2 threads from Trash.`
```

It seems that there has been a change to the functionality recently.

Comment: If you know it's not working anymore, why you post it as answer, kind sir?

Comment: It is not an answer