# How to login into Gmail to make an HTTP request using Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, httprequest, gmail-api

I have the following code to erase some drafts using the method described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete#javascript) using a HTTP request:

```
function cleanUp2() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash is:draft");
  Logger.log(threads.length);

  var userId = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
  var options = {
   'method' : 'delete',
   'muteHttpExceptions': true
 };

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    Logger.log(messages.length);

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      if (messages[j].isDraft()){
        Logger.log('id msg: ' + messages[j].getId());
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/' + userId + '/messages/' + messages[j].getId();
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
        Logger.log(response);            
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

However, the response of the fetch is the following:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

So my question is how do I login into Gmail to get the HTTP request working?

Comment: Why don't you use google [Advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) and use this instead: Gmail.Users.Messages.trash(userId, id), rather than making an elaborate call to the API.

Comment: because i get an error using Gmail.User:Messages (it worked before, but not now)... details of why it doesn't work are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930853/permanently-delete-only-one-gmail-message-from-a-thread-using-a-google-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an authorization header in your request like so:

```
//Code above this remains the same
    var userId = 'kurokirasama@gmail.com';   
      var options = {
       'headers':{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
       'method' : 'DELETE',
       'muteHttpExceptions': true
     };
//the code below remains the same
```

Note ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() works here because you have GmailApp call made by your script, so your script has the token to access GMAIL API. If don't make a call to GmailApp in the script, the token will not have scope to access your Gmail.

Alternatively, you can use advanced services in App scripts; **Resoruces>Advance Services > Gmail APi (on)** and use the below code to achieve the same result:

```
function cleanUp2() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash is:draft");
  Logger.log(threads.length);

  var userId = 'kurokirasama@gmail.com';

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    Logger.log(messages.length);

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      if (messages[j].isDraft()){
        Logger.log('id msg: ' + messages[j].getId());
        Gmail.Users.Messages.trash(userId, messages[j].getId())
        Logger.log(response);            
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!!, the header has what i was missing.  what does Gmail.Users.Messages.trash do? send to trash?

Comment: Yep, it does. Also you can use delete instead of trash if you want to delete it permanently.

Comment: for me Gmail.Users.Messages.delete doesn't work... that's the reason i'm doing it with a http request... details of why it doesn't work are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930853/permanently-delete-only-one-gmail-message-from-a-thread-using-a-google-script, if you are interested...