# Unthread or permanently delete individual gmail messages, without turning off threading

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have documents coming in through E-mail from a scanner.

The scanner CANNOT change the subject. All email subjects from scanner are same "Scan to E-mail Server Job"

However, each file name is unique.

Google threads the messages, and I generally want to keep threading on.

I run a script to extract the PDF and put on drive, and then send the message to the trash.

The problem is.. future scans run the same script on the entire thread, so I end up with numerous copies of the same exact document every time the script is run.

I looked here and elsewhere this: 
[permanently delete only one gmail message from a thread using a google script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930853/permanently-delete-only-one-gmail-message-from-a-thread-using-a-google-script)

```
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
```

EXPECTED BEHAVIOR: Don't run the script on messages in the trash.  The problem is, the whole thread is labeled trash.

ACTUAL BEHAVIOR: It runs the script on the entire thread.. even the messages in the trash from same sender with same subject.

GOAL: 
Permanently delete messages so the script doesn't run on prior messages with same subject.

OR change subject to filename after receipt and stop threading on a message after its attachment is extracted

OR add a label that applies to a single message (not a thread) that doesn't clog up my labels/folders.

ALSO, to clarify, I can't just check for the filename being unique... because they are often renamed in the drive.

***The last 2 lines below from http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/fetch-gmail-attachment-to-google-drive-using-google-apps-script are not working.  The entire thread gets reprocessed... and all attachments get added again.***

```
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j in mesgs){
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var isImageType = checkIfImage_(attachment);
        if(!isImageType) continue;
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(label);

    //ADDED BELOW TO MOVE TO TRASH
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
    threads[i].removeFromThread();


  }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#removefromthreadsthreads for my reference

Comment: When you want to completely delete a message in the thread without breaking down the thread, the method of Users.messages: delete in Gmail API can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete) But from your question, I'm not sure about the part of your script for using this method. So can you provide your current script? I would like to confirm your script and think of the solution and/or workaround.

Comment: Hello, I am using this: http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/fetch-gmail-attachment-to-google-drive-using-google-apps-script

and https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/blob/master/Code.gs

The problem is listed in the limitations section.  Everything has the same subject and same sender so it gets threaded.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. In your script, several threads are retrieved and all messages in each thread are retrieving. But in your question, it seems that the thread is constant. If the existing one thread ID is constant even when new message is received, how about checking only messages without checking all threads using the thread ID, and completely deleting the messages after the attachment files were retrieved?

Comment: Is the script running on a trigger or are you doing it manually? if on a trigger you could just retrieve the latest message. If you're doing it manually then Tanaike's approach would work best, after looping through the attachments, use the message (`mesgs[j]`), get its ID and use it with the `Users.messages: delete` method as suggested above.

Comment: Yes, the script is running on a trigger/ minute timer.  Tanaike's suggestion would work too but requires redoing the whole script that runs on threads which I am not 100% sure how to do.  

The script trigger runs every minute.  **I'll look into msgs[j] Users.messages: delete. **  Does delete actually delete or send to trash? The problem is if the thread is in the trash... any new message runs a loop on the entire thread!

Comment: About `**I'll look into msgs[j] Users.messages: delete. ** Does delete actually delete or send to trash?`, the official document says `Immediately and permanently deletes the specified message.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete) About `if the thread is in the trash`, when the method of `Users.threads: delete` is used, the thread is permanently deleted. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/delete) Will these information modify your script?

Comment: Thanks! This seems really complicated above my level.  Is this within the same code.gs file?
I tried to add `mesgs[j]: delete`

I'm not sure how to add javascript to code.gs?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize. **At the script of my answer, the thread and all messages in the thread are permanently deleted. Please be careful this. So I would like to recommend to test using a sample thread before you run the script for the actual email.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to completely delete the messages in a thread and you want to also permanently delete the thread, after all attachment files were retrieved from all messages in the thread.
- The subject of thread is always the same.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this answer, your script in your question was modified. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

When the thread is deleted using the method of `Users.threads: delete`, all messages in the thread is also deleted. This is reflected to your script.

**In this method, the thread and all messages in the thread are permanently deleted. So please be careful this when you test it.**

#### Modified script:

In this modification, 3 lines were added to your script in your question. Please check the following modified script. Before you run the script, please set the variable of `subject` which is used for checking the subject.

```
var subject = "sample subject"; // Added: Please set the subject of the thread.
var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
for(var i in threads){
  if (threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() == subject) { // Added: Here, "subject" is checked.
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j in mesgs){
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var isImageType = checkIfImage_(attachment);
        if(!isImageType) continue;
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }
    }
    Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", threads[i].getId()); // Added: Here, the thread and all mesagges in the thread are permanently deleted.
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).
- From your question, I could understand that the subject of the first message of the thread is always same. Using this, when `subject` is the same with the subject of the first message of the thread, all attachment files are retrieved and the thread is permanently deleted.
- **In this method, the thread and all messages in the thread are permanently deleted. So I would like to recommend to test using a sample thread before you run the script for the actual email.**
- If there are several threads which have the same subject at the first message, above modified script is run for them. Also please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Users.threads: delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/delete)

Comment: Thanks - I tried this and it did not work.  Is it because of "me" -- the emails are coming from an alias, to an alias.  
E-mails from scanner are coming from images@mydomain.com and going to alias scanner1@mydomain.com  ? (And yes I have subject = "Scan to E-mail Server Job").  I have also enabled the Advanced Google Services for Gmail for this script

Comment: @B D Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to write this. Before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). In my understanding of your situation, you can use `me` of `Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", threads[i].getId());`.

Comment: @B D And also, about `did not work.`, can you provide the detail information?

Comment: Thanks! I think this was my error.  I had to change the query higher up in the code to be `query = 'in:inbox to:scanner1@mydomain.com has:attachment' + query;`

Your help, as always, is AMAZING :)

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.