# can't use this google proposed function

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

there is this function [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete#javascript), that if you run it in the "try this api" section, works fine...

However, if i implement it like this (deleteMessage):

```
function cleanUp2() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("SOME SEARCH");
  Logger.log(threads.length);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    Logger.log(messages.length);
    
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      if (messages[j].isDraft()){
        Logger.log('me' + 'id msg: ' + messages[j].getId());
        deleteMessage('me',messages[j].getId());
      }    
    }
  }
}
    
    function deleteMessage(userId, messageId) {
      var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.delete({
        'userId': userId,
        'id': messageId
      });
      request.execute(
        function(resp) { });
    }
```

it doesn't work and i get the following error on line 2 (of function deleteMessage) that says (translated from Spanish so i don't know if it will be a exact translation): "a name (?) is missing behind (after?) operator ".""

Can you point out what i'm doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Did you debug the script? What are the parameters currently fed into the function at that point in time?

Comment: the error appears before executing anything, it doesn't even save the file....

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the tags I understand that you are using the Google App Script, not a standalone JavaScript. That example does not apply to Google Apps Script and will not work there.

If I understand correctly, you wish to remove all drafts from your account. Well you also have access to GmailApp and can easily accomplish what you want using it with even fewer steps. So let's say you go to `Resources → Advanced Google services...`, enable `Gmail API` and call it `Gmail`. Then the following code will delete all the drafts for the current user

```
function clearDrafts() {
  var Drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();  
  for (var i = 0; i < Drafts.length; i++)
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', Drafts[i].getId());
}
```

This function will delete all drafts without removing the actual received messages. So for example if you received an email, hit reply, typed something and ran this function, it will delete the draft, but the received email will remain intact.

Comment: Hi, my original script was using Gmail.Users.Messages.remove, but now it doesn't work anymore. Gmail.Users.Threads.remove works, but if the draft is in a thread with more than one message, all thread is deleted and not only the draft. The funcion deleteMessage deletes only the draft. 
The full explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930853/permanently-delete-only-one-gmail-message-from-a-thread-using-a-google-script

Comment: Is there a way to adapt deleteMessage to a google app script?

Comment: I believe the API still has the ability to move message to trash. You can also use `Message.remove` as well and it will work (I have tested both options), you simply should just look at the drafts folder only, which will include anything that is in any other threads as a reply.

Comment: I got and error using Message.remove (it worked before) so that's why i'm trying this

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán Hm, the `Threads` bit actually did not work when I went back to try it again. I updated my answer to just leave `Messages.remove` as that is the one that you will want. See the updated answer for a working function.

Comment: but for me is the opposite, `Threads` executes and `Messages` don't... In my previous comment is the link to the post with the details of the error if you are interested

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', Drafts[i].getId());` and **not** `gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.delete`? The only error I see you referance is the `a name is missing behind  operator "."` which is caused by using a non existing `gapi` call

Comment: Hi, Gmail.Users.Messages.remove give me the error i describe in the post i linked. And thanks to you now i know why the function of this post doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use GmailApp to move the message to draft ([can't delete mail using GmailApp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15995904/5995040)).

Now, if you want to delete the email permanently use [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced):

> To see which Google APIs are available as advanced services, look for the "Advanced Google Services" section in the [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/). If you want to use a Google API that isn't available as an advanced service, just connect to it like any other [external API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).
>
> To use an advanced Google service, follow these instructions:
>
> 1. In the script editor, select **Resources > Advanced Google services....**
> 2. In the dialog that appears, click the **on/off** switch next to the service you want to use.
> 3. At the bottom of the dialog, click the link for the **Google API Console**.
> 4. In the console, click into the filter box and type part of the name of the API (for example, "Calendar"), then click the name once you see it.
> 5. On the next screen, click **Enable API**.
> 6. Close the Developers Console and return to the script editor. Click **OK** in the dialog. The advanced service you enabled is now available in autocomplete.

I've updated your code:

```
function cleanUp2() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("SOME SEARCH");
  Logger.log(threads.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    Logger.log(messages.length);

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      if (messages[j].isDraft()){
        Logger.log('me' + 'id msg: ' + messages[j].getId());
        deleteMessage('me',messages[j].getId());
      }
      else{
       Logger.log('me' + 'id msg: ' + messages[j].getId() +" not draft");
      }
    }
  }
}

    function deleteMessage(userId, messageId) {
      Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, messageId);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

## UPDATE:

[image]

After running the code:

[image]

Try checking if you've enabled the Advance Google Service.

Comment: Hi, that was my original script, but now the function Gmail.Users.Messages.remove doesn't work anymore... Thast question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930853/permanently-delete-only-one-gmail-message-from-a-thread-using-a-google-script