# Automatically delete emails from gmail account spam folder which contain specific keywords

Tags: javascript, email, automation, gmail

In the past I have used a simple google apps script snippet to delete all spam email from my Gmail account  once an hour. This solution worked however it meant I sometimes would not receive emails from people that Google chose to move to the spam folder. I decided the best solution would be to delete only the emails which contained certain keywords. After failing to find an example online of how to do this I came up with a solution after some research on the [Gmail apps script](https://script.google.com/) [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts)

Script source: [Google Apps Script - Gmail, delete forever e-mails in trash with specific label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995031/google-apps-script-gmail-delete-forever-e-mails-in-trash-with-specific-label)

The original code to delete all email:

```
function deleteForever(userId) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:spam");

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, threads[i].getId().toString());
  }
}
deleteForever("[your_email_here@gmail.com]")
```

Please note that "in:spam" can be changed to any location in your Gmail account. Be very careful when choosing the threads you wish to delete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run the script with a few changes:

```
    function deleteForevers(userId='me') {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:spam");

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    if (msg.getPlainBody().match(/prizes|miracle|darling|(real estate)|(nigerian prince)/gi) !== null){
        Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(userId='me', threads[i].getId().toString());
    }
  }
}
deleteForevers("[your_email_here@gmail.com]")
```

**Note:** before using the script, you need to enable the advanced service [GmailApi] ([from Google Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?authuser=0&hl=he#enable_advanced_services))

Comment: Good find, I found another approach, I will update my answer to reflect the new solution, thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

The solution required two pieces of information I didn't have before:

1. the getPlainBody() method for getting a message's text
2. the javascript match function

Rather than blindly deleting every message in the threads variable I use a very basic regular expression to match a list of keywords and only delete messages which match.

When using this script add a pipe | between words and wrap phrases which contain spaces in parentheses as shown below.

```
function deleteForever() {
  // create filter text to search email body
  var filterBodyWords = "real estate offers|our offer";
  // create filter text to search email subject
  var filterSubjectWords = filterBodyWords;

  // Access the Spam folder in your Gmail account
  var threads = GmailApp.getSpamThreads();

  // Loop through each thread in the Spam folder
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();

    // Loop through each message in the thread
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      var subject = message.getSubject();
      var body = message.getBody();

      // Check if the word "rent" is in the subject or body
      if (subject.toLowerCase().match(filterBodyWords) || body.toLowerCase().match(filterBodyWords)) {
        // Delete the email
        console.log(subject)
        message.moveToTrash();
      }
    }
  }
}
deleteForever();
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: It won't work anymore, the `Gmail` class no longer exists, and its replacement - `GmailApp` has no such method